# Unity Tweak Tool Doesn't work. Schema missing. org.gnome.nautilus.desktop

Tags: 18.10

my problem is this.
I recently installed Ubuntu 18.10, but I did not like the desktop interface, so I went back and installed the version of Gnome 3.30. The problem is that I had Tweaks in the previous version and I disabled the icons on the desktop. When I changed, the Tweaks option did not appear to enable desktop icons, so I tried Unity Tweak Tool, but when I started it, It says that the org.gnome.nautilus.desktop schema is missing.

Could you help me? Either to appear the icons on the desktop or to init Unity Tweak Tool. Thank you very much!

Comment: The `unity-tweak-tool` is for adjusting the Unity desktop, not the Gnome one.  `gnome-tweaks` is for adjusting Gnome.  *Unity is a fork & variation of the gnome desktop, so many parts of it are identical, but it's still a different desktop (like cinnamon & other forks)*

Comment: ooh, ok! Thanks a lot! Do you know why in gnome-tweaks doesn't appear de desktop option already?

Comment: If you look at `gnome-tweaks` (https://packages.ubuntu.com/cosmic/gnome-tweaks or via command) you'll note it comes from 'universe' repository (*community supported*).  Only packages from 'main' (*or Canonical supported*) are included on install media, 'universe' and other repos are added by users, and may have shorter supported-lives (esp. applies to LTS releases).  Refer to https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu for more info on repositories.

Answer (score 1):

The `unity-tweak-tool` is for adjusting the Unity desktop, not the Gnome one. `gnome-tweaks` is for adjusting Gnome.

*Unity is a fork & variation of the gnome desktop, so many parts of it are identical, but it's still a different desktop (like cinnamon & other forks)*

`gnome-tweaks` (https://packages.ubuntu.com/cosmic/gnome-tweaks or via command `apt-cache show gnome-tweaks`) comes from 'universe' repository (*community supported*). Only packages from 'main' (*or Canonical supported*) are included on install media, 'universe' and other repos are added by users, and may have shorter supported-lives (for LTS releases). Refer to https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu for more info on repositories.